# Ionic 6 apps running on simulator are not debuggable using safari web inspector

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

After updating to the latest Xcode Version 14.3. Ionic 6 applications running on simulator with iOS 16.4 cannot be debugged in safari web inspector.

In other words, Safari 16.1 is showing under Develop -> Simulator Name -> No Inspectable Applications

Tested the application to run under Cordova platform iOS 6.2.0 and 6.3.0 by running

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --target "TARGET_SIMULATOR_ID" --livereload -lc
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug, you need to have [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) instead. Regular Safari does not work.

Comment: I have tested with both Safari and Safari Technology Preview. Both gave the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76434768/19561942

> After looking into this more, it seems the problem has been fixed on
> cordova-ios, however ionic uses it's own webkit.
>
> So the fix would have to be applied to Ionic's plugin:
> https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
>
> I found there is already a pull request on that plugin with the fix:
> https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/pull/677
>
> I was able to get the inspect working for me locally by forking the
> master branch, applying the changes then updating my package.json like
> so:
>
> `"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "github:< YourGithubUsername>/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"`