# Ionic app - Cordova - Safari Debug not working

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, safari, cordova-ios

In the past I was able to run my Ionic Cordova app onto my iPhone and plug it into my Mac, then open Safari on my Mac and go to Develop -> PHONE_NAME -> localhost to inspect my app.

Currently when I go to the Develop menu, PHONE_NAME shows up however, the app does not show up as an option.

If I open Safari on my phone it shows up as an option so I know it works, just not with my Ionic app.

I saw that cordova-ios 6.3.0 mentions they fixed a bug with this:

> This release contains a fix to allow inspecting of WebView content with the
> latest iOS and Xcode versions. It also fixes an iOS 16 bug and issues
> with NodeJS 18.
> Blockquote

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2023/04/15/cordova-ios-release-6.3.0.html

But after updating to cordova-ios 6.3.0 the problem persists.

Any ideas what else to try?

Mac OS Version: Ventura 13.4

iPhone iOS Version: 16.5

xCode Version: 14.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

To fix the problem just update your cordova-plugin-ionic-webview to the newest version (5.0.1 at the time of writing this)

**Original Post:**

After looking into this more, it seems the problem has been fixed on cordova-ios, however ionic uses it's own webkit.

So the fix would have to be applied to Ionic's plugin:
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

I found there is already a pull request on that plugin with the fix:
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/pull/677

I was able to get the inspect working for me locally by forking the master branch, applying the changes then updating my package.json like so:

```
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "github:< YourGithubUsername >/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
```

Comment: This was also the fix for me as well.  Great job finding this out!  Really frustrating that the fix was put in to the cordova-ios webview engine, but Ionic is still lagging.

Comment: Linking this answer to my other answer for the SO question that is the top of the Google results for "[No Inspectable Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76679795/4114403)" since that's what most of my searches ended up getting me too.

Answer (score 4):

In CDVWKWebViewEngine.m add this below code to work

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 160400
    // With the introduction of iOS 16.4 the webview is no longer inspectable by default.
    // We'll honor that change for release builds, but will still allow inspection on debug builds by default.
    // We also introduce an override option, so consumers can influence this decision in their own build.
    if (@available(iOS 16.4, *)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        BOOL allowWebviewInspectionDefault = YES;
#else
        BOOL allowWebviewInspectionDefault = NO;
#endif
        wkWebView.inspectable = [settings cordovaBoolSettingForKey:@"InspectableWebview" defaultValue:allowWebviewInspectionDefault];
    }
#endif
```